# React/JavaScript: Using React spread to performing 2 changes(at the same time) on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to rename 'timestamp' in my array with key/value pairs.  Currently, I am adding id and assinging a value but I also need to change 'timestamp' to 'start'.  Is it possible to do all that at once?

Here is what I have so far:

const { data } = this.state

```
const newAction = data.action.map((actionItem, index) => ({
  ...actionItem,
  id: index + 1,
  ...actionItem,
  'start': actionItem.timestamp 

}));
const items = {
  ...data,
  action: newAction
};
```

Data Structure:

[image]

Update:

So, instead of replacing timestamp with start, the code above adds start to array. I want `timestamp` to be named `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with spread syntax.

```js
const action = [
  {
    Second: [],
    action: "Program Executed",
    timestamp: 12345,
  },
    {
    Second: [],
    action: "Something Happened",
    timestamp: 67891,
  }
];

const newAction = action.map( ( actionItem, index ) => {
  const { timestamp: start, ...rest } = actionItem;

  return {
    ...rest,
    id: index + 1,
    start,
  }
});

console.log( newAction );
```